# making collapsed p:panel uncollapsed on validation errors for fields inside the panel

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a page, in which the form fields are divided into multiple panels like address, phone , main details etc. I wanted to keep some panels collapsed for the sake of look and feel, rather than have to scroll down. And on submit button if there are any validation errors in any of the input fields, then uncollapse those panels to show the errors. Right now the panels remain collapsed with the errors,and hence confusing the user as to why the ui is not responding.The xhtml is as follows

```
 <p:panel id="agencyAddressPanel" style="margin-bottom: 10px"
                toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" header="Address"
                collapsed="true" widgetVar="agencyAddress">
    <div class="Container25 Responsive25">
        <div class="ContainerIndent">
            <p:outputLabel for="city" id="cityLbl" style="float:left;"
                                            value="City:" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Container25 Responsive25">
        <div class="ContainerIndent">
            <h:column>
            <p:inputText styleClass="Wid80 Fleft" maxlength="30"
                id="city" placeholder="City" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please enter City."
                value="#{manageAgencyBean.agency.latestAgencyAddress.city}"
                validatorMessage="City must allow alphanumeric, special character '-' and 3 - 40 characters long.">
            <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="40" />
            <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-. ]+$" />
        </p:inputText>
        <br />
        <p:message for="city" />
        </h:column>
    </div>
</div>
<p:commandButton id="updateBtn" value="Update"
icon="#{Locale['btn.img.edit']}" type="submit" update="@form"
action="#{manageAgencyBean.confirmSave}" styleClass="Fright">
</p:commandButton>
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirmation"
  message="Are you sure you want to modify the Agency ?">
<h:panelGrid cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" columns="2"
  styleClass="centeredPanelGrid">
    <p:commandButton value="#{Locale['btn.yes']}" type="submit"
        id="yesBtn" update=":agencyForm"
        action="#{manageAgencyBean.saveAgencyDetails}"
        oncomplete="PF('confirmation').hide();PF('statusDialog').hide()           javascript:window.location='#messages'"
        onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" />
 <p:commandButton value="#{Locale['btn.no']}" type="button"
                        onclick="PF('confirmation').hide();PF('statusDialog').hide()" />
        </h:panelGrid>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

The managed bean methods are

```
    public void confirmSave() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.execute("PF('confirmation').show();");
    }
     public void saveAgencyDetails() {
         //dao call and other business here
     }
```

I am using confirmSave() to call the confirmation widget which will show a dialog box confirming the saving of details. This arrangement was done to fire the validations before the confirmation dialog box.
ALl those things are working, my problem is collapsing and uncollapsing the panels if validation error messages are there. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed) PF('agencyAddress').toggle()"` to achieve this

Before Validation:

[image: Before validation]

After Validation:

[image: After validation]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form id="testForm" >
        Current Phase: #{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal}
        PostBack: #{facesContext.postback}
        Validation failed: #{facesContext.validationFailed}
        <p:panel id="agencyAddressPanel" style="margin-bottom: 10px"
             toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500" header="Address"
             collapsed="true"
             widgetVar="agencyAddress">
             <p:outputLabel for="city" id="cityLbl" style="float:left;"
                  value="City:" />
             <p:inputText styleClass="Wid80 Fleft" maxlength="30"
                id="city" placeholder="City" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please enter City."
                value="#{testView.city}"
                validatorMessage="City must allow alphanumeric, special character '-' and 3 - 40 characters long.">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="40" />
                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9-. ]+$" />
             </p:inputText>
        </p:panel>

        <p:commandButton action="#{testView.saveMyCity}" process="@form" update="@form" value="Save my city"
        oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed) PF('agencyAddress').toggle()"/>

     </h:form>  

    </h:body>
</html>
```

My Managed Bean:

```
 @Named
 @ViewScoped
 public class TestView {


  private String city;

  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }

 public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
 }

  public void saveMyCity(){
    System.out.println("city: "+city);
  }

 }
```

EDIT: OP asked

> This is working @Mahendran, the only caveat is toggling makes it unusable, meaning if the panel is already open[collapsed=false] then it closes the panel, defeating the purpose, am trying to add more constraints onto the oncomplete function. Please let me know if you have any pointers.

use the expand and collapse methods PF('agencyAddress').expand() and PF('agencyAddress').collapse()

```
 <p:commandButton action="#{testView.saveMyCity}" process="@form" update="@form" value="Save my city" oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed) PF('agencyAddress').expand()"/>
```

Comment: This is working @Mahendran, the only caveat is toggling makes it unusable, meaning if the panel is already open[collapsed=false] then it closes the panel, defeating the purpose, am trying to add more constraints onto the oncomplete function. Please let me know if you have any pointers.

Comment: amazing!. Thanks @Mahendran. Its sure is working. Is there a documentation or anything which you can point to see the list of functions like expand(), toggle etc?

Comment: in github this is for panel --> https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/907f0a6d49ae50223cc98074b55b5d10d80c8764/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/panel/panel.js